# PHP - Unicode Problem conversion in json output

Tags: php, json

The outputted string in json is:

```
 \u062e\u0637\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u062d\u0631\u0627\u0632 \u0647\u0648\u06cc\u062a
```

I tried `json_decode` with and without `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but no luck. Something like:

```
echo json_decode('\u062e\u0637\u0627\u06cc \u0627\u062d\u0631\u0627\u0632 \u0647\u0648\u06cc\u062a');
```

It returns nothing!

Comment: json_decode() requires valid json so you need to wrap the string in double quotes (which is json notation for a string): `json_decode('"\u062e....\u062a"');`

Comment: Thank you @MagnusEriksson It must be wrapped with '[{"\u062e....\u062a"}]' too.

Comment: No, you don't need `[{` and `}]`. Just the quotes: `"the text"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Magnus Eriksson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65459290/php-unicode-problem-conversion-in-json-output#comment115729337_65459290), it must be something like:

```
print_r (json_decode("...json output..."));
```

Comment: Again, the `[` and `]` aren't necessary.